# How to get a list of all combinations of boolean values?

Tags: recursion, boolean, scheme, racket

I would like to create the following function, all-combs, that behaves as in the examples. Why does not my code work? Could you fix it or give your own code?

```
(all-combs 0)
>> '(())
(all-combs 1)
>> '((0) (1))
(all-combs 2)
>> '((0 0) (0 1) (1 0) (1 1))

(define (all-combs1 n)
  (cond
  [(equal? n 0) '(())]
  [else
    (append (map (lambda (x) (cons 0 x)) (all-combs1 (- 1 n)))
    (map (lambda (x) (cons 1 x)) (all-combs1 (- 1 n))))
 ]))
```

Comment: It works! I should have said n - 1 rather than - 1 n

Comment: You are calling `(all-combs1 (- n 1))` twice, and so you double the time of execution. You could change the last branch of the conditional in something like this: `(else (let ((lst (all-combs (- n 1)))) (append (map (lambda(x) (cons 0 x)) lst)  (map (lambda(x) (cons 1 x)) lst))))))`

Answer (score 2):

The way to get all combinations of something, in general, is with [`cartesian-product`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._cartesian-product%29%29) applied to *n* copies of the list of possible values.

The way to apply a function to *n* repetitions of a value is by using [`apply`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._apply%29%29) with [`make-list`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._make-list%29%29):

```
#lang racket

;; for combinations of booleans
(define (all-boolean-combinations n)
  (apply cartesian-product (make-list n '(#t #f))))

;; for combinations of integers 0 through 2
(define (all-0..2-combinations n)
  (apply cartesian-product (make-list n '(0 1 2))))

;; for combinations of any list of possible values
(define (all-combinations n possible-values)
  (apply cartesian-product (make-list n possible-values)))
```

Your example with 0 and 1 would be this:

```
> (all-combinations 0 '(0 1))
'(())
> (all-combinations 1 '(0 1))
'((0) (1))
> (all-combinations 2 '(0 1))
'((0 0) (0 1) (1 0) (1 1))
> (all-combinations 3 '(0 1))
'((0 0 0) (0 0 1) (0 1 0) (0 1 1) (1 0 0) (1 0 1) (1 1 0) (1 1 1))
> (all-combinations 4 '(0 1))
'((0 0 0 0) (0 0 0 1) (0 0 1 0) (0 0 1 1) (0 1 0 0) (0 1 0 1) (0 1 1 0) (0 1 1 1)
  (1 0 0 0) (1 0 0 1) (1 0 1 0) (1 0 1 1) (1 1 0 0) (1 1 0 1) (1 1 1 0) (1 1 1 1))
```

Comment: Thanks, I just added that and explained that it gives n repetitions of a value.

Comment: great; I've edited for clarity, hope you don't mind. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are very close. The problem is that you are switching the minuend and the substrahend. `(- 1 2)` does not become `1` less than `2` but `-1`. `(- 1 n)` is clearly not the intended order of arguments.

```scm
(define (all-combs n)
  (if (zero? n)
      '(())
      (let ([rest-of-combs (all-combs1 (- n 1))])
        (append (map (lambda (x) (cons 0 x)) rest-of-combs)
                (map (lambda (x) (cons 1 x)) rest-of-combs)))))
```

**I have done some extra undeeded changes as well:**

Since you did `all-combs1` on the same dataset twice it would perform very poorly on large numbers. It's easily omitted by using a `let` binding and using the result twice instead.

Since your case analysis only have one predicate, one consequent and one alternative it would perhaps be easier to read it using `if` rather than `cond`.

`equal?` can be used on any data type and will be `#t` for everything that looks the same. For numbers it's sufficient to use `eqv?` or `=` which is only for numeric values. When seeing `=` like in `(= a b)` you know `a` and `b` are supposed to numbers while `(eqv? a b)` can be number, characters, or symbols. Using a more specific procedure might be faster, but the report does not require that of an implementation. `(zero? n)` does the same as `(= n 0)` but without needing to specify the second operand and is slightly clearer of the intension.